# Evaluation of classifier using ROC curve in the presence of rare events

Tags: machine-learning, roc, rare-events

For binary classification problems where the data is highly imbalanced, i.e. much more negative samples than positive samples, it is recommended to evaluate the performance of a classifier using the ROC curve because it does not depend on the actual ratio between positive and negative class (see e.g. [He et al](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5128907)). Yet, I recently came across an article that stated that rare events are usually "better predicted" when looking at the ROC curve. Unfortunately, I did not save the article and was unable to find it again so far.

Therefore, I decided to ask here if someone could point me to a paper that demonstrates this behaviour or can give an explanation where this comes from. My follow-up questions would then be, what the preferred way is to evaluate a classifier under these circumstances.

Comment: It is not clear that classification is the right approach, as opposed to prediction.  It is also not clear how an ROC curve helps whatever the approach.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You are saying that classification and prediction are two separate things. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, quite separate.  Prediction means you are not needing to specify a loss (utility; cost) function and the end result for the analyst is the predicted probability of an outcome.  Classification means that you are explicitly or implicitly assuming a loss function (how?) and are making the decision for the consumer/reader.

Answer (score 6):

Let us try it out. Generate positively correlated quantitative classifier variable and binary state variable (0="negative", 1="positive"). And supply 3 weighting variables. Weight1 makes distribution 0/1 = 45/45. Weight2 makes it 15/75 (i.e. positive event is frequent). Weight3 makes it 75/15 (i.e. positive event is rare).

```
classifier    state  weight1  weight2  weight3
     .801         0        3        1        5
     .270         0        3        1        5
     .253         0        3        1        5
     .220         0        3        1        5
     .142         0        3        1        5
     .229         0        3        1        5
     .352         0        3        1        5
     .341         0        3        1        5
     .198         0        3        1        5
     .169         0        3        1        5
     .525         0        3        1        5
     .533         0        3        1        5
     .395         0        3        1        5
     .586         0        3        1        5
     .072         0        3        1        5
     .776         1        3        5        1
     .772         1        3        5        1
     .813         1        3        5        1
     .507         1        3        5        1
     .112         1        3        5        1
     .664         1        3        5        1
     .979         1        3        5        1
     .877         1        3        5        1
     .414         1        3        5        1
     .887         1        3        5        1
     .675         1        3        5        1
     .514         1        3        5        1
     .793         1        3        5        1
     .622         1        3        5        1
     .468         1        3        5        1
```

Weight the data with the weight variables one by one and perform ROC (I did it in SPSS). Below are statistics for Area under the curve.

```
Area    Std. Error(a)   Asymptotic Sig.(b)  Asymptotic 95% Confidence Interval  
                                              Lower Bound   Upper Bound
Weighted by weight1:
.840        .045            2.76045E-008             .753          .927
Weighted by weight2:
.840        .056            3.45509E-005             .731          .949
Weighted by weight3:
.840        .064            3.45509E-005             .715          .965

(a) Under the nonparametric assumption              
(b) Null hypothesis: true area = 0.5
```

You may notice that Area is the same, be the positive event rare, frequent or in-between. However, Error of the Area and other statistics around it are affected by whether the positive event is rare, frequent or in-between. The shape of curve itself (shown below) is not affected. So, background "rareness" of positive event has no impact on the choice of optimal classification cut-point in the classifier variable.

[image]